# Is using "both of you" along with "each other" redundant?

Tags: grammar

> OK, things are going well, both of you are enjoying each other's company,
>   and both of you are attracted to each other.

Is the usage of "both of you" correct? Sounds a bit off to me.

BTW what part of the language "both of you"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is correct in the sense of being understandable, but you're right that it sounds awkward. I think it's because "both of" is unnecessary:

> OK, things are going well: you are enjoying each other's company, 
>   and you are attracted to each other...

('Both of you' is a noun phrase, I think.)

Answer (score 1):

"Both of" is a determiner (specifically a quantifier) used in noun phrases. It is syntactically equivalent to "all of", "most of", "some of" etc. (The 'of' can sometimes be omitted from all (of) these phrases, but that depends on the definiteness and specificity of what follows: it is required here).

I find "both of" awkward here not just because of the repetition, but also because of "each other": to me, that already implies both, so it is redundant in both cases. It is nevertheless grammatical.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with redundancy, particularly if it is used for emphasis.  A large number of the uses of "both" are not strictly necessary, but draw emphasis to the fact that you are dealing with two of something — no more and no less.  In this particular example, I see "both of you" being used in this way to *emphasize* that it is a mutual enjoyment and attraction, even though "each other" already conveys that by itself.  Then, the repetition of "both of you" emphasizes this point even further.  In the end, doing this is a matter of the author's style, of course.